# Creating and setting a link element in a new html page in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to accomplish the following and my approach isn't working currently. Hopefully the SO community can help! Thanks in advance.

Goal: user clicks a button on page A and it opens page B and sets page B's link element in the head to point to a css file.

Problem: I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'head' of undefined
```

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/intelligence_ai/Lx09wxaa/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
   test element
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    let win = window.open;
    let link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    link.setAttribute('href', '/stylesheets/my.css');
    win.document.head.appendChild(link);

   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the `window.open` function:

```
let win = window.open(); // Notice the parenthesis
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tndnt36z/

If you inspect the source of the new window, you'll see that `link` tag you created, and the text.

Comment: thanks works perfect. (will mark correct, SO is making me wait 7 minutes before I can).

Comment: how would I append to the body? win.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild('<div> hello world</div>'); isn't working https://jsfiddle.net/intelligence_ai/q5rs8Lxj/3/

Comment: @RonI I was wrong about `document.head` (I changed my answer). Your append to the body is not working because `appendChild` expects an HTML element as a parameter, but you are giving it a string. Take a look at my updated JS Fiddle to see how you can do it.

Comment: follow up question here in case you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366062/external-stylsheets-in-new-window